# How to use except() for a controller instead of controller methods?

Tags: filter, laravel

I just started learning Laravel framework today.

I would like to check for user's session globally. I put a filter in the constructor of the base class like below.

```
class Base_Controller extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->filter('before', 'auth')->except(array('login@index'));

    }

}
```

it works fine except that there is one problem. I would like to ignore the auth filter for the login controller. How do I do that?

I tried

**except(array("login"))**, **except(array("login.index))**, and **except(array("login@index"))**. None of them worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$this->filter()` in a controller has a different approach that doing it in the `routes.php` file. When you use it inside a controller, `except()` will just accept methods of that controller.

You can solve your problem creating a new controller that extends from `Base_Controller` like `Base_Auth_Controller` that checks for the auth filter. You could probably use the `Route::filter('before', function(){});` and then just `return;` if you detect that the controller is 'Auth' (tip: `Request::route()->controller`) but you can't definitely exclude a `controller@action`.

Or do something like:

```
public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

    // you should check what exactly returns, I don't remember actually
    if(Request::route()->controller != 'Auth_Controller')
    {
         $this->filter('before', 'auth')->except(array('login@index'));
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for the input. var_dump( Request::route()->controller ) returns NULL... though.

Comment: mmm... you're right, it doesn't works on the class constructor but it works on the before() action. I think that the `$this->filter()` only works on a constructor anyway. Can you check the `Route::filter('before', function(){});` on `routes.php`? I'm updating the answer.

Comment: @udexter // it doesn't work in before filter as well. It doesn't return NULL, but it's empty string.

Comment: I've used Request::uri() instead for now.